# more friendly cut results as 1,2,3 instead of the hard to review ranges

Tags: r

```
d <- c(3,4,2,5,4,7,6,5,8,9,5,6,3,1,2,6,3)
```

`cut(d,3)` produces the following three levels: `(0.992,3.66] (3.66,6.34] (6.34,9.01]`.
Is there a way to present the results as levels 1,2,3 instead of these ranges?

I would like to see the results look like this `(1,2,1,2,2,3,2,2,3,3,2,2,1,1,1,2,1)` indicating element d.1 was in cut 1, element d.2 was in cut 2 or the middle tier...

Within the help for the `cut()` it said "If a labels parameter is specified, its values are used to name the factor levels" so I tried `cut(d,3,lables=c(1,2,3))`, but that didn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `factor(cut(d,3), labels=1:3)`

For details, `?factor`

By the way, `cut(d, 3, labels=1:3)` works for me as well.

Answer (score 2):

setting `labels=FALSE`, you get a nice output:

```
d <- c(3,4,2,5,4,7,6,5,8,9,5,6,3,1,2,6,3)
cut(d, 3, labels=FALSE)
 [1] 1 2 1 2 2 3 2 2 3 3 2 2 1 1 1 2 1
```

see `?cut`

> If labels = FALSE, simple integer codes are returned instead of a factor.

**EDIT**

To avoid miss interpretation of numeric values, here another  alternative

```
cut(d, 3, labels=LETTERS[1:3])
[1] A B A B B C B B C C B B A A A B A
```

Comment: I'd feel safer if it were `..., labels=paste0("grp", 1:3) ` or any letter.

Comment: Less susceptible to misinterpretation. Using numeric labels does not clearly signal that cuts have been made. Could easily be interpreted as numeric values.

Comment: Lord's football numbers anyone :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work as well:

```
d <- c(3,4,2,5,4,7,6,5,8,9,5,6,3,1,2,6,3)
as.numeric(factor(cut(d,3)))
```